# How to watch on change of select with ng-change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Any idea how can I update the total when the selected value changed? http://jsfiddle.net/yx97x0xk/1

```
angular.module('app', ['QuickList']).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.getSum = function() {
    return $scope.myJson.map(function(x) {
      return x.price * x.qty
    }).reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b
    });
  }

  $scope.myJson = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "banana",
    "price": 12,
    "qty": 3,
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "watermelon",
    "price": 12.9,
    "qty": 4,
  }]

})
```

Comment: check if this helps-- http://jsfiddle.net/7L4uhcbn/

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon how the getSum function get updated?

Comment: getSum gets called every time the digest cycle is executed which happens every time a selection happens. because we are using ng-model to keep track of the questities the digest cycle process the entire screen the model changes. thats the beauty of angular.  you can count on things just happening. :)

Comment: but u bind to json.qty not myJson. that's strange for me.

Comment: because json === myjson[index] objects in javascript are passed as references so the changes made to json are flected on myjson[index]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `ng-model="json.qty"` in your `select` tag and remove `ng-selected` from `option` tag. This will do the trick. :-)

Angular will automatically execute a function (`getSum` in this case) if the returning value from the function changes.

See it working below:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.getSum = function() {
    return $scope.myJson.map(function(x) {
      return x.price * x.qty
    }).reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b
    });
  };

  $scope.myJson = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "banana",
    "price": 12,
    "qty": 3,
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "watermelon",
    "price": 12.9,
    "qty": 4,
  }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
  <div ng-repeat="json in myJson">
    <li>{{json.name}}</li>

    <select name="" id="" ng-model="json.qty">
      <option ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]">{{$index + 1}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <h1>total:{{getSum()}}</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same, clearly. One is used solely in the controller; the other is a directive on an input element.

But even in their application they differ.

When you use $watch the watched expression will be evaluated on every digest cycle, and if there is a change, the handler is invoked.

With ng-change, the change is restricted to a user action on a particular input element.

With ng-change, the handler is invoked explicitly in response to an event.

With $watch, change can come from anywhere: user action, controller function, service - all will trigger the handler.